# java multithreading not utilizing all cores

Tags: java, multithreading, nlp, executorservice, stanford-nlp

I have a multi-threaded program which doesn't seem to actually utilize all cores in my machine. Here is the code and any input would be highly appreciated.

> Main Class

```
public class MainClass{
 public static void main(String [] args){
  Work work=new Work();
  work.doIt();
 }
}
```

The second class creates the tasks and hand them to the ExecutorService, here is the pseudo-code

```
public class Work{
 public void doIt() throws InterrputedException, Exception{
  map=get some data and put it in the map;
  ArrayList<Future<Integer>> list=new ArrayList<Future<Integer>>();
  ArrayList<WorkCallable>jobs=new ArrayList<WorkCallable>();
  for each entry in the map;
    jobs.add(new WorkCallable(entry);
  int numCores=Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
  ExecutorService executor=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numCores);
  int size=jobs.size();
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    Callable<Integer> worker=jobs.get(i);
    Future<Integer> submit=executor.submit(worker);
    list.add(submit);
  }
  executor.shutdown();
  while(!executor.isTerminated()) {}
  do something with the returned data;
}
}
```

The Callable class

```
public class WorkCallable implements Callable<Integer>{
 @Override
 public Integer call() throws Exception{
   Properties props=new Properties();
   props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos");
   StanfordCoreNLP pipeline=new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
   for(String id:entry.keySet()){
   Annotation document=new Annotation(entry.get(id));
   pipeline.annotate(document);

   process the data;
   return an integer value;
 }
}
```

The problem is that, when I check how many threads are running, I found only very few and it seems that the executor is not taking advantages of ideal cores!

I hope the description is clear.

**Update**:

- The library used is the StanfordCoreNLP package to process the text passed to the Callable object as a Map of documentID and its content. Processing the data is not an issue as I have that working just fine without the inclusion of the StanfordCoreNLP library. In other words, shallow processing of the documents works fine and utilize all cores. But when I include this package it doesn't.

Comment: Your busy-waiting with `while(!executor.isTerminated()) {}` takes one core right there. You shouldn't be doing that. There's `awaitTermination` for your purpose. BTW what exactly is the number of "very few" and how many cores you know for a fact that you have? Better yet, what does `System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())` print?

Comment: The description is not very clear also. "Load some libraries" and "process the data" both sound like potentially synchronized operations, which may knock out all threads but one from the running state.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Marko and mazaneicha. I agree that loading the libraries might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows then the JVM will delegate the thread sheduling the the NT Kernel.  POSIX type operating systems map the OS threads directly with the JVM and schedules co-operatively.

However, whatever happens, you won't be able to ensure that the threads are assigned evenly across the cores/processors.   Something else on the OS could be running on core 4 when you start your 4th thread, so it might get scheduled towards another core.  Or the scheduler could decide to stack them on the same core.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Well, even if something is running on core 4 that should show up as a running process which it doesn't and the core id ideal as far as top and htop are concerned.

Answer (score 0):

At this point with the information you have provided I would suspect that there is some contention among threads so probability is that some of threads are blocked/ waiting.  To verify this you can use JVisual VM and take thread dump(Jconsole is also an option). JVisual VM is utility to monitor java Application and comes with JDK. If you haven't use that before this would be good investment of your time to learn about it as it is very useful and simple to use.

[See Here for JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html)

1. Connect to you program using JVisual VM Take Thread dump.
2. It would provide you state of threads in your program at that
   instance of time, if there is contention and/or blocking it would be easy to
       spot using thread dump.
3. Feel free to paste it here in case you cannot make out what is
   happening in Thread dump, though there are number of resources for
   you to understand thread dump on web

On other note as pointed out by @Marko you could be more efficient in handling executors shutdown and I would say ExecutorCompletionService would fit your requirement and make code more elegant and easy to read. [Check here for ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) Once you figure out idle cores may be you can refactor to use ECS.

Comment: Many thanks soody for your detailed comment. I will check the resources you posted and get back with more details.